# JS framework for client-side to communicate with rest-api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, frameworks, client-side

I'm looking for a lightweight js framework to implement client-side web-app that would communicate with server through rest api.

I thought about react.js - but my colleagues refused to use it due to lack of any templating. Angular.js is too big - my project will use only a couple of pages and lazy-load content + send some stuff over rest api.

Any ideas? What would you prefer?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why is Angular too big? It has a built in component for dealing with Rest resources, and if you don't like that, there's other Angular libs like [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) as well!

Comment: React has things like JSX and https://github.com/petehunt/rendr-react-template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS + [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) for RESTful interaction is a breeze.

1. Config the Restular provider and set your base url for your endpoints:

```
app.config(['RestangularProvider',function(RestangularProvider) {

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://api.yoursite.com/');

}]);
```

2. Inject Restangular into you controller and use it:

```
angular.module('my.controllers')
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {

    var user = Restangular.one('user', user_id);
    var info = user.one('info');
    info.get().then(function(res) {
        $scope.userInfo = res.data;
    });

}]);
```

3. Access `userInfo` in your view

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <pre> {{userInfo | json}}</pre>
</div>
```